# System Process PID 4 Attempt to connect to many risky IPs using local port 137

Tags: network, malware, attacks, virus

I noticed in our APT solution that many endpoints in my company initiate connection attempts:

```
Process initiate: system process PID 4
Remote risky IP 185.94.111.1
remote port: random remote ports
local port: 137
```

This is really strange and seems these endpoints infected, right?

Comment: This needs more details. What is running as PID 4? The IP is in Russia but is that unusual for your company? Are these connections new or have you only just noticed them? You need to start an *investigation*. Are these incoming connection (it seems so) or outgoing connections? If your machines are "infected", then you are assuming these connections are outgoing.

Comment: PID 4 is the system process. tcp\137 is Netbios name services, so what you are seeing is all your windows PCs exchanging browse lists, voting on masters, etc. This is all windows file and print sharing services. generally these protocols should be isolated within the lan, and defintiely should not be exposed to the public internet. Does your organization have a firewall?

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments, there several missing details about this scenario:

- Is it usual/unusual that endpoints in your network communicate with IP addresses located in Russia?
- Which OS are the endpoints based-on?
- Which proccess is running as PID 4?
- ...

However, based on the information already provided, there are three facts I would focus on:

1. Several security-related vendors (at least [Cisco](https://talosintelligence.com/reputation_center/lookup?search=185.94.111.1), [Fortinet](https://fortiguard.com/webfilter?q=185.94.111.1)
   and [Symantec](https://sitereview.bluecoat.com/#/lookup-result/185.94.111.1)) report the address 185.94.111.1 as a malicious
   address.
2. Port 137 (local port in the connection attempts) is a [system port
   assigned to Netbios Name Service](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?search=137); not the kind of dynamic port
   that would be used to initiate a regular client connection to a
   remote server.
3. There are known cases of malware leveraging Netbios for
   [propagation](https://www.mcafee.com/blogs/other-blogs/mcafee-labs/analysis-wannacry-ransomware/) or [C&C communication](https://community.jisc.ac.uk/blogs/csirt/article/trickbot-analysis-and-mitigation).

Taking these three facts into account, such connection attempts look to me suspicious enough to go for further, deeper investigation.

Comment: Dears. sorry for insufficient details but unfortunately we have no more details ! there is no Parent processes, no child processes, only we know the process PID4 which is system process (seems to be infected ) and it initiate  the connections to this risky IP leveraging port 137 which is not exposed to internet but it is outbound connection). The PCs running win 10 with F-secure AV.